# Why does populating my Select Box from a SP with a parameter break the page, Classic ASP

Tags: stored-procedures, asp-classic

I have a classic asp page that has some select boxes on it. The boxes that are populated by a stored procedure that does not include an input parameter work fine.

My problem happens when I have a select box that I need to populate with a specific list of records. This is based on the current record the user has open, which I pass as a parameter to a stored procedure. I having the following code to call the SP:

```
'Return Possible RTA Contracts
Dim RecordsetApply
Dim RecordsetApply_cmd
Dim RecordsetApply_numRows

Set RecordsetApply_cmd = Server.CreateObject ("ADODB.Command")
RecordsetApply_cmd.ActiveConnection = GLData_connection_STRING
RecordsetApply_cmd.CommandText = "return_rtacontractlist"
RecordsetApply_cmd.CommandType = adCmdStoredProc
RecordsetApply_cmd.Parameters.Append RecordsetApply_cmd.CreateParameter("ContractIDParam", adVarChar, adParamInput, 50)
RecordsetApply_cmd("ContractIDParam") = RecordsetContract__GLColParam

Set RecordsetApply = RecordsetApply_cmd.Execute
RecordsetApply_numRows = 0
```

This works fine as far as the select box populating with the correct data, but the rest of the page HTML stops rendering. Here is the code for the select box:

```
<td><span id="sprytextfield24">
            <select style="font-size:12px" name="rtacontract" id="rtacontract">
                <%
                While (NOT RecordsetApply.EOF)
                    %>
                    <option value="<%=(RecordsetApply.Fields.Item("ContractID").Value)%>"><%=(RecordsetApply.Fields.Item("ContractDesc").Value)%></option>
                    <%
                    RecordsetApply.MoveNext()
                    Wend
                    If (RecordsetApply.CursorType > 0) Then
                        RecordsetApply.MoveFirst
                    Else
                        RecordsetApply.Requery
                    End If
                    %>
                </select><br />Apply Remainder To*<br />
            <span class="textfieldRequiredMsg">Field Required</span></span></td>
```

If I remove the parameter and actually hard code the record in the SP then the page loads normally. Of course this wont work as a solution though.

Hoping this is a simple mistake I have made since I am fairly new to this.

Comment: What does the conditional statement after Wend do?

Answer (score 0):

The server side code itself look fine. Most likely the data you get is "breaking" the HTML (e.g. containing raw HTML) so better encode it to be on the safe side:

```
<option value="<%=Server.HTMLEncode(RecordsetApply.Fields.Item("ContractID").Value)%>"><%=Server.HTMLEncode(RecordsetApply.Fields.Item("ContractDesc").Value)%></option>
```